# Apart from living beings, does Paramatma exist in atoms of non living material world also?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, brahman, atma

In Bhagavad Gita, Lord Krishna says that *ParamAtma* exists in the hearts of all living entities.

Question: Does he exist even in atoms of the non living material world?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**.

You are mostly referring to below verse:

> अहमात्मा गुडाकेश सर्वशयस्थितः। अहमादिश्च मध्यं च भूतानामन्त एव च
>   BG 10.20 - I am the Supersoul, O Arjuna, seated in the hearts of **all living entities**. I am the beginning, the middle and the end of all beings. -- translation ISKCON

The meaning of "भूत" also means "existence", dead or alive. This can be confirmed by below verse.

> यच्चापि सर्वभूतानां बीजं तदहमर्जुन। न तदस्ति विना यत्स्यान्मया भूतं चर-**अचरम्**
>   BG 10.39 - Moreover, O Arjuna, whatsoever is the seed of all beings, that I am. There is no thing moving or **non-moving** which can exist without Me.

Where non-moving things can be interpreted as Those entities which can't move by themselves (i.e. electrons don't move with their own wish) -- hence this include non living entities as well.

Comment: Does Paramatma exist each and every atom of my body? not only me but also in every once body?

Comment: @suri, yes. Parmatma is present in every minutest matter. But then you may ask "What is Paramatma?". Param = Beyond & Atma = Self. What is beyond everything? If you imagine the whole universe, then you will find that everything describable is within it. There is  "Nothing" (i.e. undescribed) which is beyond universe. This "Nothing" is called Paramatma. Buddhist call it "*Shunya*" (void) & Krishna called it as "Me" (self). Everything came out of Nothing, will go back to Nothing and is described with respect to Nothing. Gita also calls it the "subtlest among subtle (*sulshma*)".